# String Comparison Not Returning True

Tags: php

I am trying to compare two strings `"welford.me"` & `"welford.me"`, however, when I do `$server ("welford.me") == $allowed ("welford.me")` it does not return true. What on earth could be causing this? I've attached an image of the JSON response (which is false).

Here's the culprit:-

```
$server = parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'], PHP_URL_HOST);
$data = $result->fetch_assoc();
$allowed = explode(",", $data['api_allowed_domain']);
$found = false;
$Ajax->response['hm'] = array();
foreach($allowed as $xtld){
    if($xtld == $server){
        $found = true;
    }else{
        $hm = array($server => $xtld);
        array_push($Ajax->response['hm'], $hm);
    }
}
if($found){
    return "true";
}else{
    return "Domain / does not have permission to use this API key.";
}
```

`$server = "welford.me"` and "welford.me" is in the allowed domains listed in the database. All output is done upon destruction. Everything else works fine except this. Looks like $found is not being set to true.

[image]

Comment: You really need to add your code to this question. The JSON response looks like it's two objects, which you can't compare with `==`

Comment: Put your complete code how you are decoding this JSON response and checking.thanks

Comment: Updated and added code which is causing the problem.

Comment: @JoshWelford - where do you define `$server`? I'd recommend adding in `var_dump`, so you can see exactly what the variables are that you're trying to compare.

Comment: Ugh. Sorry, totally missed that. I've added the missed code. $server = "welford.me" and "welford.me" is in the list of allowed domains.

Answer (score 0):

Trimming both `$xtld` & `$server` seemed to work for me.

```
foreach($allowed as $xtld){
    if(trim($xtld) == trim($server)){
        $found = true;
    }
}
```